# VS 2019 Community - How to install MSBuild MT Task?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

How can I install the [MT Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/mt-task?view=vs-2019) with VS 2019? Which option at the installer includes this task? Or do I have to install the VS 2019 Build tools additionally?

Tried to use the MT task in a build target like this:

```xml
<Target Name="CreateEmbedManifest">
  <MT EmbedManifest="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Do you have the "Desktop Development with C++" workload installed as an option for "VS 2019" (or the "Build Tools for VS 2019")? The workload shoudl include the MSBuild C++ specific tasks. (Note: The difference between "Visual Studio" and "Build Tools for Visual Studio" is primarily the GUI IDE. Everything in "Build Tools" is available in "Visual Studio", but "Build Tools" doesn't include the GUI IDE.)